# Calculating Hex address after pushing 4 bytes? I don't understand how this calculation is done

Tags: assembly, binary

Here is the slide.

So Our stack is at HEX 8000 (32768) and we subtract 4 bytes from it to allow for
the element being pushed on.

How does HEX 8000 minutes 4 bytes result in 7FFC? I understand 7FFC is 32764 and that is 4 bytes minus 32768 but that is because I checked with a calcualtor. What is the method implied in the slides? Also what addresses do the rest of the values go into?

Thank you.

Comment: Hexadecimal: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

Comment: The question makes very little sense. You seem to be asking why 0x800 - 0x4 == 0x7FFC, but you already explained that when you convert them to base-10, you get 32768 - 4 == 32764, so that seems pretty obvious. You've already answered your own question. There's no way for us to answer, "*What addresses do the rest of the values go into?"*, because we don't know what values or addresses you're talking about. There is no context for this question.

Answer (score 1):

counting up in base 16

```
0x7FF8
0x7FF9
0x7FFA
0x7FFB
0x7FFC
0x7FFD
0x7FFE
0x7FFF
0x8000
```

so count backward four from 0x8000.

Any base, base 10 which we are used to has 10 symbols per position, so the ones column the 10 to the power 0 column goes from 0 to 9, then we have to increment the next column which is the 10 to the power 1 column or the "tens" column in base 10.  So after 9 we get 10, then that goes to 19 and we do this again 20 to 29 and so on to 99 then we go to 100.

Base two we have two symbols, the first column is the 2 to the power 0 or ones column the next is 2 to the power 1 or twos column the next is 2 to the power 2 or fours column, and so on.  Just like base 10.  we have two symbols so we count from 0 to 1 then we need to roll over into the next column 10 11, then we need to roll over again 100 101 110 111 then 1000 and so on.

base 8 or octal we have 8 symbols 0 to 7, we count from 0 to 7 then we increment one in the 8s column and go from 10 to 17 then increment another in the 8s column and so on to 77 then we need to increment the 16s column 100, 101, ... 107, 110, ... 117, 120, and so on.

Base 16 has 16 symbols 0 to 9 then A to F so we go from 0x0 to 0xF then 0x10 to 0x1F then 0x20 to 0x2F and so on...